# Why could this not create a buffer strategy?

Tags: java, exception, awt

I am getting an `Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.InternalError: Could not create a buffer strategy` error that traces way back into Java's base code, it traces through the Game class below at the lines, 58 ( `render();` ) and 77 ( `this.createBufferStrategy(5);` ).

Any help would be great, I have also uploaded all of my code on github (mitisme/mit) if you need to see the other classes.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private boolean isRunning = false;
   private Thread thread;
   private Handler handler;

   //Creates background window size and holds objects by handler
   public Game() {
      Screen myScreen = new Screen(1280, 720, "Deed", this);
      start();

      handler = new Handler();
      addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
      handler.addObject(new Player(425, 745, ID.Player, handler));

   }

//starts a new thread
   private void start() {
      isRunning = true;
      thread = new Thread(this);
      thread.start();
   }
   // Stops current thread, and catches exceptions
   private void stop() {
      isRunning = false;
      try {
         thread.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   //Infinite game loop
   public void run() {
      this.requestFocus();
      long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
      double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
      double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
      double delta = 0;
      long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
      int frames = 0;
      while(isRunning) {
         long now = System.nanoTime();
         delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
         lastTime = now;
         while(delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            delta--;
         }
         render();
         frames++;

         if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            frames = 0;
         }
      }
      stop();
   }

   public void tick() {
      handler.tick();
   }
   //Holds extra frames before showing (3 extra)
   public void render() {
      BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
      if(bs == null) {
         this.createBufferStrategy(5);
         return;
      }

      Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
      /////////////////Renders background first, then handlers///////////////////

      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillRect(0,0,1280,720);

      handler.render(g);

      /////////////////Updates graphics////////////////////
      g.dispose();
      bs.show();

   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      new Game();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of an uncontrollable `while(isRunning)` loop?

Comment: the youtube video I am following does it that way, I don't know how to use swing, im really new at this kind of coding aswell.

Comment: 1) Learn how to do animation before attempting 'advanced' animation with buffer strategies & such. 2) Simple animations are done in a `JPanel` using a Swing `Timer` to call `repaint()`. 3) And use Swing throughout, in the 'simple animation' path. There are many advantages to using Swing, one of which is that people will remember how to use it, and care when it fails. 4) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the line, `this.createBufferStrategy(5);` can only create buffer strategy from 2-4, otherwise it gives error.